# is there a better way to implement simple function to multiple element in a DIV and to work only if its click in jQuery

Tags: html, jquery, css, css-selectors

This work perfectly but I will want more professional way because I want to follow the rule of "don't repeat yourself".

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    $(".child:first").click(function(){
        $(".hire-me:first").fadeIn("slow");
      });
    
    $(".child").eq(1).click(function(){
        $(".hire-me").eq(1).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".child").eq(2).click(function(){
        $(".hire-me").eq(2).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".child").eq(3).click(function(){
        $(".hire-me").eq(3).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".child").eq(4).click(function(){
        $(".hire-me").eq(4).fadeIn("slow");
    });
    $(".child").eq(5).click(function(){
        $(".hire-me").eq(5).fadeIn("slow");
    });
});
```

Please I need a short way to implement this.

Comment: Use function argument number. Example: `function toggleElement(number) {...}` and use `number` instead of `eq(n)`.

Comment: Please show up what you tried to solve this problem. _Hint_: you can create a function with a `for` loop that uses the index inside the `eq()` call.

Comment: I have a button that I want to display whenever I click on his parent div that they are all children of the same div, example: a card that has a button that will on show when you clicked on it and I only want his button to appear not all the buttons on all the cards. As you can see I query both the children and the buttons to fade in when I clicked their parents.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you require you can use the `index()` method to determine the index of the current `.child` element. You can then use this dynamic value in the `eq()` method calls you make.

```js
$("document").ready(function() {
  $(".child").click(e => {
    let index = $(e.target).index();
    $(".hire-me").eq(index).fadeIn("slow");
  });
});
```

```css
.hire-me { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="child-container">  <a href="#" class="child">Child #1</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">Child #2</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">Child #3</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">Child #4</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">Child #5</a>
  <a href="#" class="child">Child #6</a>
</div>

<div class="hire-me-container">
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #1</div>
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #2</div>
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #3</div>
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #4</div>
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #5</div>
  <div class="hire-me">Hire Me #6</div>
</div>
```